# lua table constructor with keys containing spaces

Tags: lua

i know i can construct tables like this:

```
local t= {
    first = "value1",
    second = "value2"
}
```

and i now i can use keys containing spaces like `t["some key"] = "some value"`
but is there a way to construct table like above with keys containing spaces?
I tried a few things, but i only goit errors

Answer (score 8):

You can declare any expression as a key in a table constructor by putting it in brackets:

```
local t = {
  ["some key"] = "some value",
  [234567 + 2] = "other value",
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
local t= {
    first = "value1",
    second = "value2"
}
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
local t= {
    ["first"] = "value1",
    ["second"] = "value2"
}
```

This convenient syntax only works for names. Lua names may only consist of letters, numbers and underscore and they must not start with a number.

As a valid Lua identifer may not contain a space you cannot use the syntactic sugar. Hence the only way to do this is to use the full syntax

```
local t = {["hello world"] = 1}
```

This also applies to indexing that table field. So the only way is `t["hello world"]`